# Removing small areas from raster layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster with the extent of some sinks. I need to delete the sinks smaller than 10 square metres, because they are not important for my project.

[image]

How could I accomplish that? (It's basically the same problem as here: [Removing small "salt & pepper" polygons from layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73585/how-to-remove-small-salt-pepper-polygons-from-a-layer), only for raster instead of vector data...)

Comment: Perhaps by vectorizing the raster first with http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html, selecting the small polygons and saving them to a shapefile and finally burning white pixels into the original raster with http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html by using the shapefile as data source.

Answer (score 22):

I suppose your pixel size is 10m². You could use the `gdal sieve` function you can find in the Raster menu to remove lonely pixels. You can also launch it by searching in the command line :

```
Processing algorithm: Sieve
```

Details : http://www.gdal.org/gdal_sieve.html

> The gdal_sieve.py script removes raster polygons smaller than a
> provided threshold size (in pixels) and replaces replaces them with
> the pixel value of the largest neighbour polygon. The result can be
> written back to the existing raster band, or copied into a new file.

I think the polygon word is not really appropriate but the tool should do what you want without going through heavy polygon vectorisation. You can raise the value to remove bigger areas or should your pixel size was 1m² for example. You would than use 10 as a threshold.

For french readers, the tool is called "Tamiser" but the tool within gdal is still called Sieve.

Comment: Ah, but what about eliminating large clumps?

Comment: Depends what you call "large". You could just raise the threshold.. but you will probably remove areas you need....

Comment: But gdal_sieve.py only eliminates pixel clumps below a certain threshold. I'd like an option to eliminate clumps above a threshold.

Comment: oh I see...You should ask a new question it would be interesting to know ;)

Comment: Was there a new question posted on removing clumps above a threshold?

Comment: Just a thought, but I think a "large clump (above threshold)" filter can be achieved by using the "below threshold" (`gdal_sieve`) to create a mask, then creating the inverse of this mask and use this to mask your raster? This should **keep** all areas below threshold (effectively deleting all areas above threshold).

Answer (score 4):

1. Vectorize your raster with Raster>Conversion>Polygonize.
2. Then use the filed calculator and create a new field *area*: Function *Geometry* > $area
3. Afterwards you can filter out the small polygons (right click on vector layer)
4. Save the filtered layer to another vector layer.
5. Rasterize the filtered vector layer (Raster>Conversion>Rasterize)

Comment: An issue with this is if you raster layer contains too many noncontiguous blocks, the `Polygonize` tool can take hours.