# Calculating areas of classes in raster based on minimum required area (QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, raster

I need help for a QGIS calculation. I have a raster made up of 20 classes and I need to get the area of each one. Now, performing only this task is easy but I must also exclude from the area calculation all the class patches less than 1 ha (namely 11.2 contiguous pixels considering the raster resolution. How can I do that through raster calculator or any other QGIS tools?

Comment: Depending on the size and resolution of your raster, you could vectorise it, filter by area and then dissolve by your classes to get the total areas. Or, you can `sieve` your raster to remove the small clumps of pixels. See [this question and answers for reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/163174/128665)

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried with sieve but it assigns to pixel below the threshold to another class different from the origin.

Comment: Please add things you have already tried to your question. It will help improve the question and probably yield better answers.