# How to delete from mutipolygons all but the biggest polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, simplify

I have a bit too complex multipolygon set to be used in a web application (thematic map) so I'd like to simplify the structure by removing small islands of areas. I am not an expert on QGIS but so far I have managed to split the multipolygons into simple polygons and calculate the areas of each. I just can't remove all the islands less than some size, as some areas have bigger secondary islands than main polygon of other areas.

So I thought that the best solution would be to remove all but biggest polygons of each area. Only I haven't been able figure out or search the solution from Google how to do it on QGIS. Is there a way to do it?.

A secondary thought: There are a few areas with holes (meaning another area inside the bigger one), does my intended protocol break these holes as well?

wbr
hank

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Processing Toolbox, search for and run the "Keep n biggest parts" algorithm. If you set "To keep" as 1, you'll only get the largest part in the output.

Comment: Thank you very much. The QGIS toolbox is quite big, didn't see that